# What are good books for building techniques of LEGO Technic

Tags: technic, building, books

I've been searching for good resources for especially LEGO Technic. I find the *Unofficial LEGO Technic Builder's Guide* by Paweł “Sariel” Kmieć. The book is very good at explaining things. Beside that one are there any other books that I can learn basic to advanced building techniques of LEGO Technic?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In addition to Sariel's excellent book, I'd suggest Yoshihito Isogawa's "Tora no Maki" (Book of secrets) downloadable PDF book, and his Ideas books in print. All are full of clever mechanisms, easy to reproduce and integrate into bigger constructions.

See: [isogawastudio.co.jp](http://www.isogawastudio.co.jp/legostudio/toranomaki/en/)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Isogaway Yoshihito is without doubt one of the greatest "Technicians" of all time
here are some books of his:

https://www.google.co.in/search?q=yoshihito+isogawa+books&oq=yoshihito+isogawa+books&aqs=chrome..69i57.191j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8