# Is there any website or youtuber that can help me improve my building skills?

Tags: ev3

I joined the robotics team in my school and I find it really hard to cope with my friends when building. I need to improve my building skills before returning back to school.

Is there any website or youtuber that can help me improve my building skills?

Comment: Universal advise is to acquire experience by building more. Such way you encounter specific problems and it would be easier to know which problems/solutions you need to look for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a catalog of Lego building techniques?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/16183/is-there-a-catalog-of-lego-building-techniques)

Answer (score 4):

I'm unsure if you are trying to improve your general building skills or specific ev3. In case you are looking for tutorials on general building techniques http://www.brickbuilt.org/?cat=77 has a list of some tutorials. This site also features pictures of creations other people have made.